# GenerationType.IDENTITY overhead on PostgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

This document [states](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Identity_sequencing):

> Although identity sequencing seems like the easiest method to assign an id, they have several issues. One is that since the id is not assigned by the database until the row is inserted the id cannot be obtained in the object until after commit or after a flush call. Identity sequencing also does not allow for sequence preallocation, **so can require a select for each object that is inserted**, potentially causing a major performance problem, so in general are not recommended.

Hibernate discourages GenerationType.IDENTITY [as well](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity).

Simple repository.save (via Spring Data JPA) gives me this SQL:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('credits_id_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into fullname_credits (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into author (first_name, last_name, patronymic_name) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into string_credits (credits, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into document (basic_credits_id, main_title, edition_credits_id, edition_description, imprint_place, publication_date, publisherName) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into journal_article (endpage, designated_number, issn, series_main_title, startpage, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Hibernate: update author set fullname_credits_id=? where id=?

SQL logging is enabled with Spring's HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.showSql. GenerationType.IDENTITY is used except where `credits_id_sequence` appears.

So, seems there are no select+insert for id retrieval, therefore: how does Hibernate determine entity ids?

Comment: The first bullet-point in the chapter of the Hibernate doc that you linked to says: "If Hibernate believes the JDBC environment supports java.sql.Statement#getGeneratedKeys, then that approach will be used for extracting the IDENTITY generated keys.".

Comment: @jb-nizet well, it does, but there's no info on what's going under the hood. as far as i understand it's dependent on data source (driver, pooling) implementation even in this particular setup (hibernate+postgres), right?

Comment: Under the hood, it calls Statement.getGeneratedKeys() and relies on its contract, that is documented in the Statement javadoc and JDBC specifications. Hibernate won't re-explain all that in its own documentation. Yes, it relies on PostgreSQL JDBC driver's support for this feature.